# How do I post multiple POST requests in Angular at the same time?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, observable, angular-httpclient

I'm working on piece of work where I need to use `HTTP post` request, but it needs to be dynamic because the number of post requests to be made can vary.

I have an array of objects and I want to post each object to the `httpClient` but so far it's only successfully posted the final object of the array.

**EXAMPLE**

I have an array like this

```
const planningChannels=[
{icon: "libraryBooks", name: "Blogs", type: "custom", color: "#dc4e41", purpose: "planning"},
{icon: "instagram", name: "instagram DM", type: "custom", color: "#50e3c2", purpose: "planning"},
{icon: "pinterest", name: "pinterest", type: "custom", color: "#535353", purpose: "planning"}
]
```

and I iterate through the array with a forEach loop:

```
planningChannels.forEach(channel => {
    this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, channel)
      .subscribe(
        createdChannel => {},
        error => this.notificationsService.apiError(error),
      );
});
```

The calendarService.createChannel function look like this:

```
createChannel(calendarId: string,channel: Partial<IChannel>): Observable<IChannel> {
    const requestUrl = `/calendar/${calendarId}/channel/`;

    return this.http.post<IChannel>(requestUrl, channel).pipe(
      tap(createdChannel => {
        this.stateManager.dispatch(
          {
            id: calendarId,
            channels: [createdChannel],
          } as ICalendarUpdatedEntities,
          CalendarEntitiesFetched
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

Each time I try and run this via the Chrome browser I can see all 3 network requests, but only that one is every visible on my front end. Can anyone help me on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can answer why not all 3 is visible on the front end. But I can suggest a more optimal way of doing your http requests, by using "merge" or "concat". With "merge", all your http request will fire at the same time. With "concat" the http requests will que up and each will go after the previous finished.

Instead of your forEach loop, you can do the following:

```
const pcObservables = planningChannels.map(channel => this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, channel));
concat(...pcObservables).subscribe(
  createdChannel => {},
  error => this.notificationsService.apiError(error),
);
```

Comment: Thanks @SnorreDan, this doesn't seem to work for me. There aren't any network requests in Chrome going out. I have made a brief change to the original question where `this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, payload)` should have been `this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, channel)`, would that make any difference?

Comment: @BenNewton no I don't think that should make a difference. But I discovered I had a mistake in my code, I forgot to destructure the pcObservables array. I have now changed "concat(pcObservables)" to "concat(...pcObservables)". Maybe it works now?

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple observables in parallel using `forkJoin`.

Firstly, set up your observables:

```js
const planningChannels=[
  {icon: "libraryBooks", name: "Blogs", type: "custom", color: "#dc4e41", purpose: "planning"},
  {icon: "instagram", name: "instagram DM", type: "custom", color: "#50e3c2", purpose: "planning"},
  {icon: "pinterest", name: "pinterest", type: "custom", color: "#535353", purpose: "planning"}
];

const observables = planningChannels.map(channel =>   
  this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, payload).pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      this.notificationsService.apiError(error);
      return of(null);
    })
  )
);
```

These observables aren't executed until something subscribes to them. Notice how each observable can handle errors in its own pipe.

Now you can use `forkJoin` to run them as one observable.

```js
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(createdChannels => {
  const state = {
    id: calendarId,
    channels: createdChannels,
  } as ICalendarUpdatedEntities;

  this.stateManager.dispatch(state,  CalendarEntitiesFetched);
});
```

I have assumed that you want all observables to run even if one fails. The value returned from `forkJoin` will be an array of the same length as the input array. It will contain either the objects returned from the service, or the `null` returned from `catchError`. It would probably make sense to move the error handling into your service, but I wanted to keep my example as close to your original as possible.

Comment: Thanks @KurtHamilton, however it's still doing the same as before where it only displays 1 item when I view my front end. I did make a mistake in my original question, where `this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, payload)` should have been `this.calendarService.createChannel(calendarId, channel)`, would that make any difference?

Comment: You will want to run `stateManager.dispatch` after the responses have been returned, in your `forkJoin` subscribe. I have amended that part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that only one result is visible on the front end after executing 3 POSTS, it might be because of

```
channels: [createdChannel],
```

which is only one response in array, but not all 3 responses.
I would suggest to use forkJoin or something similar, because you will have all 3 responses in one place, which you will be able to push to the state easily.